# How do I write into a file without extra newlines?

Tags: python

I want to output some string to a file in Python. I'm adding a `\n` at the end of the line, but Python inserts additional newlines to it automatically and I don't know how to remove them.

```
for i in range(len(arrnames)):
    fout.write(arrnames[i] + " " + str(arrvalues[i]) + '\n')
```

```
dave
 302
laura
 66
owen
 -359
vick
 141
amr
 -150
```

Comment: Are you sure they're not in arrnames already? Also note you can write this more idiomatically with zip.

Comment: Perhaps you should modify the code (which you don't show here) that reads the data such that newlines are not included.

Comment: Also remember to include the expected output in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to clean your content before you print it. Try adding a string strip before concatenating

```
fout.write(arrnames[i].strip() + " " + str(arrvalues[i]) + '\n')
```

You could also try formatted string literals as an alternative to the verbose concatenation:

```
fout.write(f"{arrnames[i].strip()} {str(arrvalues[i])}\n")
```

Answer (score -3):

You are adding a newline, explicitly, at the end...
Try removing the '\n'